# Reading a list of strings into pandas dataframe results in error

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, for-loop

I want to read a text file into a pandas dataframe. In the file are several tables, each separated by an empty line. I would like to have those tables separated, so I split the text file into chunks each containing a table. Using `StringIO` I can read in a single chunk using pandas `read_csv()`. However, looping through the list of chunks that I have results in the following error: `'EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file'`

Creating the chunks from the text file

```
with open(txt_full_paths[0], 'r') as file: 
    chunks = file.read().split('\n\n')
```

Using StringIO to read single string into dataframe with read_csv(). This works as expected

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(chunks[0]), sep='\t').transpose()
```

However, when I try:

```
dfs=[]
for chunk in chunks: 
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(chunk), sep='\t').transpose()
    dfs.append(df)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
EmptyDataError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/lefebre/Allostericsiteprediction_backup/pocket_pred_clust_backup.ipynb Cell 24 in <cell line: 2>()
      1 dfs=[]
      2 for chunk in chunks: 
----> 3     df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(chunk), sep='\t').transpose()
      4     dfs.append(df)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/allostericsiteprediction/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/allostericsiteprediction/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:680, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    665 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    666     dialect,
    667     delimiter,
   (...)
    676     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    677 )
    678 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
...
     79 # error: Cannot determine type of 'names'

File ~/miniconda3/envs/allostericsiteprediction/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:551, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what's the `chunks` content?

Comment: `pd.read_csv(StringIO(""))` results in the same error, so it's likely that you have an empty chunk, probably because the file ends in `\n\n`.

Comment: Please show an example of your data.

Comment: @AlexHall thanks! You were right! Could be easily resolved with: open(txt_full_paths[0], 'r') as file: 
    chunks = list(filter(None, file.read().split('\n\n')))